# Выборка 2 элементов с одним ID

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте,

Есть интернет магазин, в корзине идет выборка товаров по ID, и нужно чтобы в корзине некоторые товары были в количестве не больше 2-х, и таким образом в 1 корзине может быть несколько товаров с 1 ID.

Но в выборке нельзя делать:

```
SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id IN (101842,101842,101838,101840)
```

Но в выборке только 3 элемента, как можно сформировать запрос, чтобы в выборке были все 4 элемента?

Comment: А что мешает получив результаты из базы, продублировать их нужное количество раз? База-то небось не знает, сколько какого товара заказано. А вы пытаетесь «впихнуть» в неё бизнес-логику.

Да, вам надо проверять, _есть ли_ столько товара, и возможно ещё резервировать (а то вдруг тем временем другой клиент купит?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в корзине ID - первичный ключ, то необходим столбец "количество". Если - не ключ, то достаточно

```
WHERE id IN (101842,101838,101840)
```

чтобы вывести все товары с одинаковыми ID.

Comment: id это как раз ключ

Comment: Ну, тогда первый сценарий - столбец с количеством + ограничение на количество больше 2-х.
Насколько я помню, MySQL не поддерживает ограничения CHECK, потому это ограничение придется реализовывать в коде приложения.

Answer (score -1):

Странная хотелка, но если очень уж хочется..

```
SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id = (101842,101838,101840)
union all 
SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id = 101842
....
```